# How Do I Restore My Clock?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, clock

When I boot Ubuntu 10 I got an error message stating that your time applet is not working properly (and yea that's true, it is not showing proper time, whereas in Windows the time is exact!).

I'm prompted to delete/not-delete the application, I have deleted it. Now how I can restore the clock, that will show the correct time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The clock applet in the top panel in Ubuntu 10.10 or 10.04 right?, right click the panel, add applet, search for the clock, add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do right click on `panel` , and click on `add applet` then `add clock` it will restore your clock and time